# How to skip `(Y/n)` prompt when running firebase login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, travis-ci, firebase-cli

I am trying to set up firebase CLI in my continuous integration (travis-ci, not that it really matters) and I inevitably have to login to firebase.

```sh
$ firebase login --token FIREBASE_TOKEN --no-localhost
]0;Firebase CLIi  Firebase optionally collects CLI usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.
? Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information? (Y/n)
```

Since it's just travis-ci, there's no way for it to answer yes or no to that prompt, which hangs and kills the build.

I did check `firebase login`'s `--help` and here's what I got:

```sh
> firebase login --help
Usage: firebase login [options]

log the CLI into Firebase

Options:
  --no-localhost  copy and paste a code instead of starting a local server for authentication
  --reauth        force reauthentication even if already logged in
  -h, --help      output usage information
```

So there doesn't seem to be any kind of override flag like `-y` or anything.

How am I supposed to log into firebase in my continuous build if there's no way to skip this prompt? Alternatively, how can I skip this prompt?

I think it can't be complicated because support for "CI Systems" is outlined in [Firebase's own docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems).

Edit: Attempted with `login:ci`

```sh
$ firebase login:ci --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
]0;Firebase CLI
Visit this URL on this device to log in:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=...
Waiting for authentication...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `firebase login` if you run commands with the flag `--token`.

```sh
$ curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
-- Checking for existing firebase-tools on PATH...
-- Checking your machine type...
-- Downloading binary from https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest
######################################################################## 100.0%
-- Setting permissions on binary...
-- Checking your PATH variable...
-- firebase-tools@]0;Firebase CLI8.4.1 is now installed
-- All Done!
before_install.2
$ firebase firestore:delete --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --all-collections --project $PROJECT_ID -y
]0;Firebase CLIDeleting the following collections:
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pointing you to use `login:ci` to provide the token directly in the command line using CI environments.  You're using `login`, which is meant for interactive shells.

Comment: i edited my post with the output when I run `login:ci` - AFAIK I only need to run this in my local shell to get a `FIREBASE_TOKEN` which I am then just supposed to add as an environment variable to my CI

Comment: Yes, you run it locally first to get the token, then use the token in CI with `login:ci`.

Comment: so what's wrong with the command i ran `firebase login:ci --token FIREBASE_TOKEN`?

Comment: You're passing the literal string "FIREBASE_TOKEN".  Instead, you need to provide the token string that you got from the first local run.

Comment: I passed it in correctly this time with `login:ci` and updated my post. same behavior :/